# How to customize Image Chooser in Wagtail?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

[image: Image Chooser]

How do I customize the Image Chooser in Wagtail? I need to block the user from having the ability to upload GIFs > ~1 MB in size. Uploading a 3 MB GIF crashes the server right now, and even a 1.5 MB GIF timed out on production. I'm using wand and ImageMagick for the GIFs, I altered the disk quota for ImageMagick but it's not a viable solution on the server, the compression takes forever. So my next step is to totally block large GIFs from being uploaded. I want to set a limit of about 1 MB for GIFs. I don't want to fork the Wagtail framework to do this. Are there any alternative suggestions to get around this GIF problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the maximum image size, either by file size or image dimensions, through the `WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE` or `WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS` settings: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/settings.html#images

Comment: Any way to specifically restrict the size of GIFs only while keeping the limit the same for other images?